# What happens if polyfill script fails to download?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, single-page-application, polyfills

I have a SPA (built on webpack, with babel, etc) that includes a polyfill in the index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise,Array.prototype.includes,Element.prototype.remove"></script>
```

One use-case for the polyfill is in order to use the Promise API on IE 10-11.

My error monitoring reporting an error on an IE 11 client of the following:

```
ReferenceError: 'Promise' is undefined
```

So I assume that particular session failed to download the polyfill for some reason.

My question is: How should I deal with this case? Is it a scenario I should expect to happen sometimes? Is the user expected to noticed the application not working properly, and reload the page?

Comment: Instead of depending on an external script, could you include its code in your main script? That way there's only one dependancy (your own site, which is essential regardless) rather than two?

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. Please see my comment to the first answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error event you can attach to allow for more control if you are really worried. You don't usually need to handle this explicitly though.

In this particular case you could migrate towards using babel to build a bundle with polyfills included in your scripts.  This adds an additional build step to your process though.

Comment: Hosting the polyfill on my site is a very reasonable suggestion. Truth be told, I chose polyfill.io because it was so easy to get running with it. But both polyfill.io and my site are hosted on the same CDN (Fastly), so should I be concerned about an extra point of failure?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you're using webpack, it would just be best to include the necessary polyfills directly in the project via an import statement (something like [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)) rather than using a cdn - polyfill.io.

However, you could alternatively add an ID to the script element and listen to the onload and onerror events to determine whether the script (un)successfully loaded like so:

```
<script id="polyfillScript" src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise,Array.prototype.includes,Element.prototype.remove"></script>
```

In your project index.js:

```
document.getElementById('polyfillScript').addEventListener('error', () => {
    alert('Failed to load polyfill!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Reda. The error event listener sounds very interesting. Is that commonly used for this scenario?

Comment: Kinda, it is more typically used in scenarios where the only way to depend on a resource is via the script tag - take google maps js api for instance.